# Need to align checkboxes horizontally in dashboardbody of shinydashboard?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to show some checkboxes based on radio button input on dashboardbody of shinydashboard. However I am able to do so but these checkboxes are not horizontally aligned. I want to make matrix of these checkboxes as three columns and multiple rows also want to align these on right side of dashboardbody not on center.

Is there anyway to achieve this ? P.S. - I have tried using checkboxgroup but I am not able to set ids for individual checkbox.

Below is code :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)
Scenario <- c("Personal Information", "Academic Information")
shinyApp(
ui = dashboardPage(title = "My Page",  
                 dashboardHeader(
                   title = "My Header",
                   titleWidth = 200
                 ),
                 dashboardSidebar(
                   width = 200,
                   sidebarMenu(
                     menuItem("My Data", selected = FALSE, 
                              menuSubItem(text = "My Data", tabName = 
   "my_data", newtab = TRUE, selected = FALSE)
                     )
                   )
                 ),
                 dashboardBody(
                   tabItems(
                     # First tab content
                     tabItem(tabName = "my_data",
                             h2("Please select fields"),
                             fluidRow(column(12,radioButtons('rbscenario', 
   NULL, Scenario, inline=TRUE))),
                             uiOutput('checkboxes',inline = TRUE)
                     ) 
                   ))),
 server = function(input, output){
 observe({
  input$absubmit
  if(input$rbscenario == "Personal Information"){
    output$checkboxes <- renderUI({
      dashboardBody(fluidRow(column(6,
                                    checkboxInput('CB_FN', 'First Name', value = FALSE),
                                    checkboxInput('CB_MN', 'Middle Name', value = FALSE),
                                    checkboxInput('CB_LN', 'Last Name', value = FALSE),
                                    checkboxInput('CB_DOB', 'Date of Birth', value = FALSE),
                                    checkboxInput('CB_GN', 'Gender', value = FALSE),
                                    checkboxInput('CB_CT', 'City', value = FALSE))),
                    actionButton('abSubmit',"Submit", icon = NULL)
      )})}
  else if(input$rbscenario == "Academic Information"){
    output$checkboxes <- renderUI({
      dashboardBody(fluidPage(
        fluidRow(column(12,
                        checkboxInput('CB_SC', 'School', value = FALSE, width = NULL),
                        checkboxInput('CB_CL', 'College', value = FALSE, width = NULL),
                        checkboxInput('CB_POS', 'Primary OS', value = FALSE, width = NULL),
                        checkboxInput('CB_PLN', 'Primary Programming Language', value = FALSE, width = NULL),
                        checkboxInput('CB_PDB', 'Database', value = FALSE, width = NULL),
                        checkboxInput('CB_NT', 'Networking', value = FALSE, width = NULL))),
        actionButton('abSubmit2',"Submit", icon = NULL)
      ))})}
  })
  })
```

[image: This is the output I am getting]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was that `dashboardBody()` was used in an incorrect location thereby creating a large left margin. Rows and columns are built up manually.

I have replaced this part of your code

```
  dashboardBody(fluidRow(column(6,
                                checkboxInput('CB_FN', 'First Name', value = FALSE),
                                checkboxInput('CB_MN', 'Middle Name', value = FALSE),
                                checkboxInput('CB_LN', 'Last Name', value = FALSE),
                                checkboxInput('CB_DOB', 'Date of Birth', value = FALSE),
                                checkboxInput('CB_GN', 'Gender', value = FALSE),
                                checkboxInput('CB_CT', 'City', value = FALSE))),
                actionButton('abSubmit',"Submit", icon = NULL)
  )
```

with

```
div(
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
           checkboxInput('CB_FN', 'First Name', value = FALSE),
           checkboxInput('CB_MN', 'Middle Name', value = FALSE)),
    column(4,
           checkboxInput('CB_LN', 'Last Name', value = FALSE),
           checkboxInput('CB_DOB', 'Date of Birth', value = FALSE)),
    column(4,
           ceckboxInput('CB_GN', 'Gender', value = FALSE),
           checkboxInput('CB_CT', 'City', value = FALSE))
  ),
actionButton('abSubmit',"Submit", icon = NULL)
)
```

to get this

[image]

Similarily, you should also replace `dashboardBody()` with `div()` under the second if condition (Academic Information).

Comment: I guess what the OP wants is to align the check boxes to "Personal Information" (no blank between the left border and the check boxes). Is this possible?